# The Boolean algebra generated by sets of prime divisors of the numbers $2^n-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\Pi$ be the set of odd prime numbers and let $\mathcal P(\Pi)$ be the Boolean algebra of subsets of $\Pi$.

For a number $x$ denote by $\Pi(x)$ the set of odd prime divisors of $x$.

> **Problem.** Does each singleton $\{p\}\subset \Pi$ belong to the Boolean algebra generated by the family $\{\Pi(2^n-1):n\ge 2\}$ in $\mathcal P(\Pi)$?

We can also ask a stronger

> **Question.** Is it true that for every odd prime number $p$ there exit numbers $n_1,\dots,n_k$ such that $\{p\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^k\Pi(2^{n_i}-1)$?

---

**Added in Edit.** The number $p=5$ mentioned in the answer of Ofir Gorodetsky gives a counterexamle to Question but not to Problem as $\{5\}=\Pi(2^4-1)\setminus\Pi(2^2-1)=\{3,5\}\setminus\{3\}$.

Comment: Not likely. Consider p=5.  (Assuming k bigger than 1, as commented above.) Gerhard "Likes Looking For Small Counterexamples" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: To respond to the edit, also not likely. Consider Zsigmondy primes. I suspect 23 and 89 are primitive prime factors (of 2^11 - 1), and provide another counterexample.  Gerhard "Thank Goodness For Small Exponents" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: Further, I suspect that replacing (-1) in the title by (+c) for some integer c (maybe c different from 15) will also yield a pair different from (but like) 23,89. Gerhard "Can Make A Wild Conjecture" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: Restatement of the **Problem**: for $p,p'\in\Pi$, write $p\sim p'$ if for every $n\ge 2$, $p$ divides $2^n-1$ iff $p'$ divides $2^n-1$. Is $\sim$ the discrete equivalence relation on $\Pi$? In turn, this can be restated as: is the function mapping an odd prime $p$ to the order of $2$ modulo $p$, injective?

Comment: ... and the sequence of orders of 2 modulo primes is [OEIS:A014664](http://oeis.org/A014664). It's indeed not injective, the first failure of injectivity are $(23,89)$ mapping to 11, which is the pair mentioned by Gerhard Paseman, then $(37,109)$ mapping to 36, then $(53,157)$ mapping to 52.

Comment: Also $\ {233,1103,2089\}$ map to $29.$ Those primes are $29k+1$ for $k=8,38,72$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^{11}-1=2047=23\cdot 89$ and neither prime divides a smaller such number. So  $23  \mid 2^n-1$ exactly when $n=11m.$ Similarly $89  \mid 2^n-1$ exactly when $n=11m.$ So $\{23,89\}$ is in the Boolean Algebra but neither of its singleton subsets is.

Here is a list for $n \leq 33$ of the set of primes which divide $2^n-1$ but not any $2^m-1$ for $1 \lt m \lt n$. These sets (excluding $\{\}$) are the atoms of the Boolean Algebra:

$[2, \left\{ 3 \right\} ],[3, \left\{ 7 \right\} ],[4, \left\{ 5
 \right\} ],[5, \left\{ 31 \right\} ],[6, \left\{  \right\} ],[7,
 \left\{ 127 \right\} ],[8, \left\{ 17 \right\} ],[9, \left\{ 73
 \right\} ],[10, \left\{ 11 \right\} ],$

$[11, \left\{ 23,89 \right\} ],[
12, \left\{ 13 \right\} ],[13, \left\{ 8191 \right\} ],[14, \left\{ 43
 \right\} ],[15, \left\{ 151 \right\} ],[16, \left\{ 257 \right\} ],[
17, \left\{ 131071 \right\} ],$$[18, \left\{ 19 \right\} ],[19, \left\{ 
524287 \right\} ],[20, \left\{ 41 \right\} ],[21, \left\{ 337
 \right\} ],[22, \left\{ 683 \right\} ],[23, \left\{ 47,178481
 \right\} ],$

$[24, \left\{ 241 \right\} ],[25, \left\{ 601,1801
 \right\} ],[26, \left\{ 2731 \right\} ],[27, \left\{ 262657 \right\} 
],[28, \left\{ 29,113 \right\} ],$

$[29, \left\{ 233,1103,2089 \right\} ]
,[30, \left\{ 331 \right\} ],[31, \left\{ 2147483647 \right\} ],[32,
 \left\{ 65537 \right\} ],[33, \left\{ 599479 \right\} ]$

Comment: Umm, how come singleton 5 is in the B.A.? Gerhard "Needs A Little More Thinking" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: Good point. Corrected.

Answer (score 7):

No. The gcd (greatest common divisor) of $\{ 2^{n_i}-1\}_{i=1}^{k}$ can be seen to be $2^{\gcd(n_1,\ldots,n_k)}-1$, by an application of the Euclidean algorithm. If $p$ divides this expression, then $\gcd(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ is divisible by the order of $2$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. In general, $2^{\mathrm{ord}_p(2)}-1$ may have prime factors other than $p$.

For instance, if $p=5$ and $p$ divides all of $\{ 2^{n_i}-1\}_{i=1}^{k}$ then each $n_i$ is divisible by $\mathrm{ord}_p(2) = 4$, and so each $2^{n_i}-1$ is divisible by $2^4-1=15= 3 \times 5$.

In fact, the answer to your question is positive only for primes $p$ such that $p^k$ is of the form $2^q-1$ for some $k$, where $q$ is a prime. (For $k=1$ these are known as Mersenne primes.)

Comment: And we can show there aren't many such p (where p^k + 1 is a power of 2) for k greater than 1.  Gerhard "Also Likes Limiting Counterexample Search" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: Right, by Mihăilescu's theorem for instance there aren't such p once k>1, thanks for the observation.

Comment: there is also an elementary argument for the base p=2. (I can post a hint if it does not occur to you.)  Gerhard "Don't Forget The Simple Methods" Paseman, 2019.12.06

Answer (score 6):

For example, if $2^n-1$ is divisible by 43, then $n$ is divisible by 14 and therefore $2^n-1$ is divisible by 127. Thus 43 is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for so quick answer to my Question. What about the Problem? Is $\{43\}$ a Boolean combination of the sets $\Pi(2^n-1)$ (like $\{5\}$)?

Comment: I do not know about 43, but Gerhard is correct that 23 and 89 are 'twins' in this algebra.

Comment: {43} is the Boolean sum of {3),{127} and the prime divisor set of (2^14) - 1.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered in comments, so I'm posting cw.

The Boolean subalgebra $A$ defined by the OP being generated by finite subsets, it is atomic. The atoms are precisely the (finite) fibers of the function $f$ mapping the odd prime $p$ to the order $f(p)$ of $2$ modulo $p$; it is given by [OEIS:A014664](http://oeis.org/A014664).

And indeed $f$ is not injective, so $A$ does not include all singletons. For instance $f(23)=f(89)=11$ (it was mentioned in a comment by Gehrard Paseman).

Hence the problem (and hence the question) has a negative answer. However the question already has a simpler negative answer, as the singleton $\{5\}$ (which belongs) to the Boolean algebra $A$ is not in the smaller set of subsets defined in the question using only finite intersections, see Ofir's answer.