# The density of the set of non-pathological primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

An prime number $p$ is called *pathological* if there exists a prime number $q\ne p$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ the number $2^n-1$ is divisible by $p$ if and only if $2^n-1$ is divisible by $q$.  According to the comment of Gerhard Paseman and @YCor to [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/347774/61536), pathological prime numbers exist and the smallest one is 23, the next is 53, then 89, 157, etc.

> **Problem 1.** How large is the set of non-pathological primes?

Is a version of the Dirichlet density theorem true for non-pathological prime numbers:

> **Problem 2.** Is it true that for every natural number $a$ and any (square-free) number $b$, which is relatively prime with $a$, the arithmetic progression $a+b\mathbb N=\{a+bn:n\in\mathbb N\}$ contains a non-pathological odd prime number?

**Added in Edit.** By [Bang's Theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24540006?seq=1), for any $n\ge 2$, 
the number $2^n-1$ has a non-pathologic prime divisor. Is this information sufficient for answering Problem 2 in affirmative?

Comment: You should talk about relative density, as the Banach density of the primes should itself be zero. You might find results of primitive prime factors (cf. results citing Zsigmondy) useful here. My guess is that (relative to the base set of the primes), the Banach density for non-path. primes is still zero. Gerhard "Also Mersenne Exponent Prime Density" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yes, I have understood that after posing the problem. But at the moment I am traveling (trains, airports, etc), so not always there is access to the Internet. Of course the density of primes is zero so all subsets of primes also have the density zero. But you suggest that the set of nonpathological primes is small in the set of all primes  or large (in the sense of Dirichlet Theorem)?

Comment: Both. Let's pretend for the moment that there are finitely many Mersenne primes. (If there are infinitely many, I suspect but cannot yet prove they provide a yes answer to 2.)  Then I think there are still infinitely many non pathological primes, enough to provide a yes answer to 2, but not enough to be positive density in the primes.  Gerhard "Based On Experience, Not Knowledge" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I looked at Zsigmondy Theorem at Wikipedia and found there that for any $n\ne 6$, the number $2^n-1$ has a non-pathological prime divisor. Is this sufficient for stating that the set of non-pathological prime numbers intersects each arithmetic progression $a+bN$ with relatively prime $a,b$?

Comment: I think you mean 2^n -1 has a primitive prime divisor for each n greater than 6.  The likelihood that such a primitive prime is pathologicial is high given large n and the growth of cyclotomic polynomials evaluated at 2 as n grows. (No proof from me, though.) Search MathOverflow for Jameson and cyclotomic to find some relevant notes. I'm guessing Problem 2 is true.  Gerhard "And Some Distantly Related Questions" Paseman, 2019.12.07.

Comment: By the way, $n=11$ is a counterexample to the edit. Bang did show that a primitive prime divisor occurs in 2^n - 1 for $n$ different from 1 and 6, and some of these are not pathological.  Gerhard "Some Edits Are Not Pathological" Paseman, 2019.12.09.

Comment: Your list of pathological primes up to 157 is incorrect. It should read: $23, 29, 37, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 131, 137, 139, 149, 157, \ldots$. The list of non-pathological primes is identical to **[OEIS A144755](https://oeis.org/A144755)** except for hypothetical Wieferich primes that are non-pathological (both known Wieferich primes are pathological; 1093 goes with 4733, 8861085190774909, and 556338525912325157; and 3511 goes with  1969111, 4242734772486358591 and [three larger primes](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000000138614564)).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen So, the set of pathological primes seems to be quite dense and there are more pathological primes than non-pathological (in the sense of density)?

Answer (score 2):

One can phrase this is terms of divisors of (values when evaluated at $x=2$ of) cyclotomic polynomials $P_n(x)$.  A pathological prime $p$ is a primitive prime divisor of $P_n(2)$ (so $p$ does not divide any $P_m(2)$ for $m$ smaller than $n$) such that there is $q$ different from $p$ which is also a primitive prime divisor of $P_n(2)$. Given the sparsity of Mersenne primes, one can find many pathological primes as divisors of Mersenne non-primes but with the exponent of this Mersenne number also being prime. So barring exceptional behaviour of the sequence of Mersenne primes, we have a potential source of infinitely many pathological prime numbers: just look at almost any Mersenne number with prime exponent ($P_n(2)$ is a Mersenne number when $n$ is prime).

When $n$ is not prime, $P_n(2)$ may yield some more pathological primes, unless it is a nontrivial power of a prime. (For $n$ bigger than 6, there will be at least one primitive prime divisor; Zsigmondy and Bang showed this, and Granville had something to add more generally about the parity of the exponent of such primes.)  However, there are some $n$ for which $P_n(2)$ is prime, and these provide nonpathological primes. Further, these primes are 1 mod n, and so knowing which $n$ these are give a start on approaching Problems 1 and 2.  Looking at Cunningham tables suggests that these primes are frequent in occurrence and possibly also infinite in number, regardless of the infinitude of Mersenne primes (which are themselves nonpathological).

**Update 2019.12.12:**

After rereading notes of G. Jameson on cyclotomic polynomials (see comments below for an indirect reference), we can be more clear on the presence of nonpathologic primes. Although one can look at P_n(a) for values of a other than 2, I stick with Taras's choice of 2. Further, for n less than 7, one can study those numbers individually, so I will speak of n bigger than 6.

Prime divisors of P_n(2) are bigger than n, except in one case: if n has a special form mq^k where q is the largest prime divisor of n and q is a primitive divisor of P_m(2), then q can also divide P_n(2). So there are two possibilities for p not to be a pathological prime: if n is not special and P_n(2) has one prime divisor (and I would expect all but finitely many to not be proper prime powers, but this is unproven), or if n is special and P_n(2) is qp^k (less is known about this, but k bigger than 1 would surprise me).

I don't know how to apply this to Will Sawin's comment. This form suggests to me that maybe the upper bound on the number of non pathological primes below X could actually be log of his suggested upper bound.  If indeed there are infinitely many, then each will be 1 mod n for some n, and when n is sufficiently large may fall into enough of the arithmetic progressions of part 2.

**End Update 2019.12.12.**

Gerhard "Tables Nice Place To Frequent" Paseman, 2019.12.09.

Comment: I guess this shows the density of pathological primes is no greater than the density of the numbers $P_n(2)$, which I guess grow roughly like $2^{\phi(n)}$ and thus almost exponentially. More realistically, if $P_n(2)$ has $\approx \frac{1}{n}$ chance of being prime then there should only be $\log \log \log X$ non-pathological primes up to $X$.

Comment: My question 221357 speaks to the growth of P_n(q) in general, and points to notes of Jameson which give more info on divisors of P_n(2). Gerhard "Going Link Lite For Now" Paseman, 2019.12.09.

Comment: Also I think Will's comment has a phrase that should instead read "the density of non pathological primes". Gerhard "What A Difference Non Makes" Paseman, 2019.12.09.